# Send ID of list-menu to ajax get function in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to load div records without page refresh.

To do this i have created :

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function(e) {
var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax/main/'+id,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
             $('#yourDiv').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

And menu :

```
            <ul class="list-group sidebar-nav-v1 fa-fixed" id="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="list-group-item list-toggle">                   
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse-typography">Menu</a>
                    <ul id="collapse-typography" class="collapse in">
                        <li><a href="#1" id="test"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"></i> Test 1 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2" id="test1"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i> Test 2 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#3" id="test2"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i> Test 3 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#4" id="test3"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> Test 4 </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

What is the correct way to get the id of href of menu items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to get click event of href(a) tag . then you will get id in "$(this).attr('id')"

```
$('.list-group-item').find('a').click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost/ajax/main/'+id,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (html) {
         $('#yourDiv').html(html);
    }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thank for the fast replay.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function(e) {
```

To

```
$('#collapse-typography a').click(function(e) {
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdbtjfxp/)**

Comment: I have a post modification question. Is there a way to remember the id so that when i use F5 it refresh the page it was on ?